# Deserializing object with dynamic property won't work

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, restsharp

I'm having troubles with deserializing an object with a dynamic field, which will hold different api responses.
This is how it looks like:

```
public class ServiceCallResult
{
    private dynamic _dataObject;
    private Type _dataType;
    public Type DataType
    {
        get
        {
            return _dataType;
        }
        set
        {
            _dataType = value;
        }
    }
    public dynamic DataObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _dataObject;
        }
        set
        {
            _dataObject = value;
        }
    }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public ServiceCallResult()
    {
    }
    public ServiceCallResult(Type type, dynamic obj)
    {
        DataType = type;
        DataObject = obj;
        Success = true;
    } 
}
```

And it could hold an object like this:

```
public class ApiPractitioner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int CVR { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public short ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] ProfileImage{ get; set; }
    //[JsonIgnore]
    //public List<ApiPractice> Practices { get; set; }
    //[JsonIgnore]
    //public List<ApiClient> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

But when deserializing with this code:

```
var req = new RestRequest("practitioner/createpractitioner", Method.POST);
req.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
req.AddBody(prac);

var response = _client.Execute<ServiceCallResult>(req);
ServiceCallResult td = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<ServiceCallResult>(response);
```

It ends up with a "MissingMethodException" in mscorlib.dll, additional information is "An abstract class can't be created".
The response object has the json content but there's and exception like the one when I use the JsonDeserializer and I can't figure out what's going on, I've searched for hours on Google and tried different suggestions with no luck.
Anyone tried the same with a dynamic property?

I'm using RestSharp for the json handling.

Best regards
Benjamin

**After a little enlightment from Michael I've changed my ServiceCallResult to this:**

```
public class ServiceCallResult<T> where T : BaseApiResponse
{
    public T DataObject { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public ServiceCallResult()
    {
    }
    public ServiceCallResult(T obj)
    {
        DataObject = obj;
        Success = true;
    } 
}
```

And all my api responses inherits from BaseApiResponse.

Comment: How do you expect the deserializer to know which object to create for the `DataObject`property? As it states it needs to create some form of object and a `dynamic`is not a type that can be instantiated. You cannot event use `object` if you wanted to. IMHO you should reconsider your design.

Comment: Hi Michael
Thanks for enlighten me - I've changed the ServiceCallResult to a more generic use and removed the dynamic and Type properties. :-)
See the result in my edited post.

Comment: And what might be your `BaseApiResponse`? Also, after the edit, do you still have the failure? How are you deserializing now?

Comment: That should work as long as you call `.Deserialize<ServiceCallResult<ApiPractitioner>>(response);`

Comment: Hi Icepickle
The BaseApiResponse is having one property field of int, nothing more.
I don't have the error anymore and the line I deserialize with is:
var response = _client.Execute<ServiceCallResult>(req);
Then the data is on response.Data :-)
I'm not using the second line: ServiceCallResult td = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<ServiceCallResult>(response);
at all.

Comment: Can't edit my response - but the code is:
var response = _client.Execute<ServiceCallResult<ApiPractitioner>>(req);